# Moving cell cursor after a hidden row is unhidden

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have hidden rows that unhide depending on the value of a cell. By default, the cursor moves **before** the rows are unhidden, and I'd like the cursor to move **after** the cells are unhidden.

I am aware of changing the cell direction to not move at all after pressing enter as this is working solution. I am just wondering if I can do it this way as it's more convienient for other users to just type in the cell, press enter, and have it go to the next correct cell.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement contain two parts:

First to trigger event, by default there is no event that comes with excel so the work around is below:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24777074/trigger-event-in-excel-vba-when-row-or-column-is-hidden

Then to move to next cell you can use line below:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
```